# How to exclude folder In Project or file, VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I'm using VS2015, as I know I could add folder or files to Include In Project, but there's anyway to exclude from Project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there's no way to exclude a folder from a Cordova project in Visual Studio. I'd suggest you add a vote for this feature on the Visual Studio UserVoice site ([Mobile App Development category](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/category/31483-mobile-app-development)) if it would be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks, Jordan. okay, now I know there's no way to do that, I'll add a vote to there. :)

Comment: Here's the UserVoice idea http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/10574700-add-exclude-folder-in-project-or-file-vs2015

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but I only recently needed the same thing. And I noticed that even in Visual Studio 2017 the option to exclude a folder or a file is still not given. But there are folders that are automatically excluded like "node_modules", so that means one way to achieve what you were looking for is project file hacking.

My requirements were only to exclude a folder, but I think you can apply the solution to files as well. Funny note: as you can see from the boiler plate project file, Microsoft intended for you to be able to exclude items, they just don't provide the option in the UI.

1. Unload your project file and right click "Edit [project name].jsproj"
2. Find the following section in the project file:

`<PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Customize which folders are not shown by default -->
    <ExcludedItems>[boiler plate stuff ...];`**your_folder_here**`</ExcludedItems>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="**\**" Exclude="[boiler plate stuff ...];**\`**your_folder_here**`\**" />
</ItemGroup>`

3. Add your folder or file at the location shown above
4. Save the file and Reload the project